# IE8 - Rounded corners in div with opacity

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pie-chart

I used filter for making div background transparent in IE8:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
```

When I wanted to make rounded corners I found PIE.htc with css

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
border-radius:10px; 
-ms-behavior: url('./../css/PIE.htc');
behavior: url('./../css/PIE.htc');
```

But when I tried to combine this code I get element with rounded corners but with no opacity. Here is a full css code for my element:

```
#frontpage .form_wrapper .form_background{
width:100%; 
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1; 
opacity: 0.7; 
background-color: #ffffff; 
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)"; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
border-radius:10px; 
-ms-behavior: url('./../css/PIE.htc');
behavior: url('./../css/PIE.htc');}
```

Is it possible at all?

---

UPD

Thanks for the answer. 
I faced with one problem:

```
-pie-background:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
```

didn't work in any other browsers except IE. So, I had to include it only for IE8. Here is my solution, maybe it can help somebody. HTML file:

```
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><div class="IE IE8andLower form_background rounded_corners"></div><![endif]-->
 <!--[if gt IE 8]><div class="IE IE8higher form_background rounded_corners"></div><![endif]-->
 <!--[if !IE]>--><div class="notIE form_background rounded_corners"></div><!--<![endif]-->
```

And corresponding CSS rules:

```
#frontpage .form_wrapper .form_background{
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; 
    opacity: 0.7; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius:10px;
 }

#frontpage .form_wrapper .form_background.notIE,#frontpage .form_wrapper .form_background.IE.IE8higher {
    background-color: #ffffff
 }

#frontpage .form_wrapper .form_background.IE.IE8andLower{ 
    -pie-background:rgba(255,255,255,.7); 
    behavior: url('./../css/PIE.htc');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a ms filter and opacity but you could use the css pie background property to acheive an rgba value:

```
-pie-background:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
```

Just remove your background-color: #fff

Comment: +1. CSS3Pie won't work in conjunction with `-ms-filter:opacity`. This is a known issue and there's lots of discussion about it in the [CSS3Pie ticketting system](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/search?q=opacity&ref=cmdform&type=Issues).